# Uninstall program when drive is disconnected

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, uninstall

I have one tricky question xD. Is there any way to uninstall program when HDD with system is connected as secondary drive. I mean when I remove HDD with system on it and connect it do other system, lets say with USB adapter. I can browse through files and folders that are on that HDD. Also I can copy/move/delete files/dirs on it. Now is there any way to uninstall installed programs on it. The same uninstall as you would do in system is running.

Thanks xD

Comment: It's unclear what your actual Problem is. Is the just the PC defect and the Disk itself still bootable on another PC? Or is the OS Corrupt so you aren't able to boot and thats why you wanna use another PC? Or don't you wanna boot it since you're talking about removing a Virus/Trojan?

Comment: Depends on the program and some other factors, the majority of programs, leaves the mechanism to uninstall the program in the same directory its installed at, without the uninstall file, you cannot reverse the changes it makes to your system

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, but only by removing program files. It is not the best option because uninstaller program cannot do proper clean-up in running operating system because you runs not the same system that application was installed.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. "The same uninstall as you would do in system is running."